# How to set a fixed bottom shadow for a scrollable div?

Tags: css, html, scroll, frontend

I'd like to set a `box-shadow` for a div that would stay in a fixed position, but would have a scrollable content. To make it more understandable, it would work like so: http://jsfiddle.net/Dud8V/ - how can I make the shadow stay in it's position even when the div is scrolling?

Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use a box-shadow for that effect, use a gradient as background instead.

Comment: @CBroe why? Previously I had an image with a gradient over there and that didn't work out because if it's above the div, I can't click on the elements that are below it inside of the main div.

Comment: _“Previously I had an image with a gradient over there”_ – there is a difference between an image _over_ something and a _background_ image …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a fixed background , http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGIrf

```
#chatroom {
  position: relative;
  height:50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, 
    blue 0 ,
    pink 50px) no-repeat top;/*linear-gradient()  can be replaced by an image url(myImage)  to include older browser */
  background-size:100% 50px;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

.chatmessage:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

Comment: Well that could be fixed with an actual image as fallback.